# Я изменил переменную PATH в Ubuntu 16.4 и теперь не могу войти в графическую оболочку. Kак исправить?

Tags: ubuntu, path

При входе в систему Ubuntu рекурсивно запрашивает пароль для входа(думаю что проблема в том что я изменил PATH в / etc/enviroment)
Что делал для исправления:

1. вошёл в консоль
2. изменил PATH в /etc/enviroment
3. source /etc/enviroment
4. перезагрузил систему

После перезагрузки проблема сохраняется, echo $PATH выводит не корректное значение(значение, которое было до шага 2), но /etc/enviroment содержит новое значение.
Подскажите можно ли как то это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылка на статью о переменных окружения в linux:
https://losst.ru/peremennye-okruzheniya-v-linux
Ссылка на инструкцию по внесению правок в PATH:
https://youtu.be/1UpPWHfuSG8

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вообще-то он и есть автор вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, где-то должен быть текст с просьбой скопировать главное в ответ. А текст про репутацию для комментариев как-то не в тему.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, был не прав, каюсь: в моём комментарии же написано про **чужие** сообщения.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте залогиниться с разных TTY: `Ctrl+Alt+F1..F7`

Потом закомментируйте ваше хозяйство в конфигах.

```
/usr/bin/nano /etc/environment
```

По уму, файл `/etc/environment` должен быть пустой.

Если разные TTY не работают, то нужно загрузить компьютер в режиме [single user mode](https://qastack.ru/ubuntu/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub).

Если у вас есть доступ к консоли, то можно просмотреть все переменные окружения, например командой `env`.

Если вам не нравятся какие-то значения каких-либо переменных, в [англоязычном сообществе](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from) можно посмотреть как с этим бороться.

Если вам нужно лишь залогиниться в графической оболочке, то проще всего удалить файлы `~/.profile`, `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xmodmap`, `~/.login`, `~/.logout`, `~/.xsession`, `~/.pam_environment`.

Только пишите полные пути до файлов, например:

```
/usr/bin/rm /home/user/.profile
```

Также убедитесь что пользователь имеет полные права на свою домашнюю папку и влюженные в эту папку файлы. Бывает, что отредактировав что-нибудь в вашей домашней папке пользователем root, ваша графическая оболочка не может прочитать какие-нибудь конфиги или тупо не может создать файл сессии из-за недостаточных прав.

```
/usr/bin/ls -la
```

или

```
/usr/bin/ls -la $HOME
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как и где изменить содержание PATH для всех пользователей?

Comment: PATH обычно меняют в `~/.profile` либо добавляют новый файл конфига в папку `/etc/profile.d`. В `/etc/profile.d` также стоит писать полные пути. Добавляя новую папку в PATH заменяя значение ни в коем случае не удаляйте текущие папки: например, `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` или `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. Не используйте для других пользователей папки внутри вашей домашней папки, т. к. у других пользователей не будет на них прав. Лучше не добавляйте ничего в `/etc/profile.d`. Для новых пользователей можете создать `/etc/skel/.profile`. Файлы из /etc/skel добавляются в папку нового юзера автоматом

Comment: Самое простое - небольшим скриптом добавить `PATH=...` всем пользователям в `~/.profile` в домашней папке каждого пользователя и для новых пользователей использовать `/etc/skel`.

Comment: Вы также можете подключить в `~/.profile` выполнение какого-то общего скрипта. Но я не рекомендую так делать, либо не редактировать скрипт после таких добавлений. Просто это все может привести к разным зацикливаниям при случайной ошибке в скрипте или ранним сохранением недописанной команды. Лучше делать топорно для каждого пользователя отдельно без централизаций.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, но пока так чего исправить не смог. Редактирование PATH в ~/. profile и ~/. baschrc не помогло.

Comment: @ИльяДементьев https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Comment: Могу войти в систему только через tty1-tty6. Проблема сохраняется для всех пользователей. Пытался исправлять конфиги через TTY. Не понимаю что нужно сделать чтоб восстановить работу графической оболочки

Comment: Да просто удалите эти файлы, где вы делали изменения. Ну или переименуйте их в какое-нибудь название, которое система не будет воспринимать, если в этих конфигах есть нужная информация...

Comment: А что пишет команда `journalctl`? Если не удается найти ошибку, можно запустить c ключем `-f` как-то так: `journalctl -f`. В таком режиме утилита будет выводить на экран информацию в реальном времени. Потом следует переключиться снова на форму ввода логина-пароля, попытаться авторизоваться. И затем снова вернуться в TTY где запущена `journalctl -f`, где можно посмотреть, на что именно ругается процесс авторизации.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо, была синтаксическая ошибка в в /etc/environment